# Cakephp3: how to return unescaped URLs in Json

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Rest application and I would like to unescape JSON URLs returned by my controller.
In AppController I have called the requestHandler:

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

And in my routes I have:

```
$routes->setExtensions(['json']);
```

And I set my response data like this:

```
$this->set(['url1' => $url, 'url2' => $url2]);
```

It's working fine but it returns escaped URLs like:

```
"https:\/\/example.com\/v1\/v\/save\/abc"
```

Is there a way to get the URLs unescaped (JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES from json_encode) ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer (to myself), put this line in the AppController or ApiController :

```
$this->set('_jsonOptions', JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```